# Setting Layout to null in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

**Is there a reason why you would want to set the Layout property to null in a _Layout.cshtml?**

For example, like this, before rendering the body view?

```
    ...
    <section id="content">
        @{ Layout = null; }
        @RenderBody()
    </section>
    ...
```

It seems pretty nonsensical to me, and removing the line setting Layout doesn't change the way page loads work observationally.

**Is there *any* reason why you would want to set the Layout property in _Layout.cshtml?**

Comment: Yes, by setting the layout null you remove the layout converting your view in a partial

Comment: @Jorge - are you saying that you would use such a line in a partial, or that by using such a line it affects partials in RenderBody()?  It seems confusing to use in a _Layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Layout pages can have a layout too. In **nested layouts** , you intentionally use **Layout** property to define super layout of layout page . By default it is null in your layout page if you do not specify any. When you make `@{Layout=null}` you are explicitly saying that this your final layout so it is not nested in any super layout.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create a partial view that will not inherit any layout from _Layout than you will use  @{ Layout = null; } in the begining of your partial view.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but my problem solved by this trick!
I like to share my solution here

- First change `_ViewStart.cshtml` to :

  `@{
   if (Layout != "")
   {
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }
   }`

As you can see `Layout` is a property and we will check that if it is not equals to `""`

- Next you have to add this in your views

  `@{
  Layout = "";
  }`

And you will have happy views without layout!