# System.NullReferenceException: System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<T>.Model.get returned null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner at MVC and trying to create a page...I have three tables in my database...I am using Entity Framework DB first approach and I created this three tables as classes under my 'Models' folder...I also created a new class called 'AllClasses' and defined each of this three classes in this new class...
I am trying to get 3 pictures from the "tblCharacter" tables "CharacterImageURL" column...
When I run my code   "return View(myclass)" I get an error => System.NullReferenceException: System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null...
The problem is `return View(myclass);` is returning NULL...So the problem is with my Controller I think...

I KNOW THERE ARE SIMILAR QUESTIONS BUT NONE OF THE SOLUTIONS WORKED FOR ME...

***This is my controller part:***

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using StarWars.Models;
    namespace StarWars.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            StarWarsFunClubDBEntities myobject = new StarWarsFunClubDBEntities();
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            public ActionResult SWHome()
            {

                var myclass = new AllClasses();
                myclass.Avatars = myobject.tblAvatars.ToList();
                myclass.Characters = myobject.tblCharacters.ToList();
                myclass.Comments = myobject.tblComments.ToList();
                return View(myclass);
            }

        }
    }
```

This is my home page SWHome.cshtml

```
@model  StarWars.Models.AllClasses


@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>SWHome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo"> <img src="~/images/Star_Wars_Logo.png" alt="Alternate Text" /> </div>
            <div class="sitename"><h4>Star Wars Fun Club</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div class="question"><h5>What do you think about the new characters of Star Wars: The Force Awakens(2015)?</h5></div>
        <div class="photo">
            <div class="innerphoto">
                 @foreach (var item in Model.Characters)
            {
                <img src="@item.CharacterImageURL" alt="" />
            }


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="comment"></div>
        <div class="addcomment"></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>



    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

THESE ARE MY CLASSES WHICH ARE AUTO-GENERATED WITH THE HELP OF EF DB FIRST

```
 namespace StarWars.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class tblAvatar
        {
            public int AvatarID { get; set; }
            public string AvatarName { get; set; }
            public string AvatarImageURL { get; set; }
        }
    }


namespace StarWars.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tblComment
    {
        public int CommentID { get; set; }
        public string Expression { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public int AvatarID { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace StarWars.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tblCharacter
    {
        public int CharacterID { get; set; }
        public string CharacterName { get; set; }
        public string CharacterImageURL { get; set; }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using StarWars.Models;
using StarWars.Controllers;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace StarWars.Models
{
    public class AllClasses
    {
        public IEnumerable<tblAvatar> Avatars { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<tblCharacter> Characters { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<tblComment> Comments { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: In which line you are getting error?

Comment: In foreach loop... Model is coming as NULL I think...

Comment: You have `List<StarWars.Models.AllClasses>` in the view but you are returning `AllClasses` from mthod `SWHome`

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: As an aside, we generally call that kind of class a ViewModel (and name it accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

You returned with method `SWHome()` the object `AllClasses` but your view excepted a `List<AllClasses>`.

Maybe is this the solution for you:

```
@model StarWars.Models.AllClasses
```

instead of

```
@model  List<StarWars.Models.AllClasses>
```

and the solution for your images:

```
@foreach (var Character in Model.Characters)
{
   @if (Character.CharacterImageURL != null) 
   {
      <img src="@Character.CharacterImageURL" alt="" />
   }
}
```

or without null check:

```
@foreach (var Character in Model.Characters)
{
   <img src="@Character.CharacterImageURL" alt="" />
}
```

Comment: @vivek nuna... I also tried => model StarWars.Models.AllClasses, but this time I am getting an error =>' CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'AllClasses' because 'AllClasses' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator' '

Comment: You can remove the foreach and then:             <img src="@Model.Characters.Where(x=> x.CharacterImageURL != null)" alt="" />

Comment: See also the answer from vivek Nuna.

Comment: I saw and commented on too. As I stated there, I think the problem is I cannot reach to property of a class...For example after Model.Character. editor supposed to show me properties of Character class... But I can not reach them.. Why? Answer of this "WHY?" is the solution for my question I think...

Comment: One problem is that the layout is null.

Comment: This helped a bit,now I reach the properties,thank you  but I have the same error again...Maybe there is something wrong with the controller part???

Answer (score 0):

You have `List<StarWars.Models.AllClasses>` in the view but you are returning `AllClasses` from method `SWHome`.

In your case you need to use `@model StarWars.Models.AllClasses`

Rempove the `foreach` loop in the View. and directly access the property like this. `Model.Characters`

Comment: I removed foreach loop and instead I have this code snippet =>  <img src="@Model.Characters" alt="" /> ..But this time I get the same NULL error for the "Layout"...I think problem is => There are three tables thus three class autogenerated . I added one class "AllClasses" to join all these three. But this time I can not reach to property of a class. For example I want to reach tblCharacter class' CharacterImageURL property but after "." operator, intellisense does not offer me this property. I can just reach class under the model but can not reach the property under this class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869398/setting-layout-to-null-in-layout-cshtml#:~:text=When%20you%20make%20%40%7BLayout,nested%20in%20any%20super%20layout.&text=If%20you%20want%20to%20create,begining%20of%20your%20partial%20view.

Comment: I am not using any layout or partial view?

Comment: The problem is => I am returning a NULL from my controller...Do you have any idea about the controller part?